# How can I generate simple test results like {testname:abc, status:pass:duration23sec} using karate

Tags: karate

There is a requirement for me to generate results in this format -
[ {"testName": "abc" , "status":"pass", "duration":2},
{"testName": "xyz" , "status":"pass", "duration":2}]
How can I acheive this using karate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider writing your own report from the data that Karate generates.

Here is a thread that is a good starting point: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/619

quote:

> maybe the easiest thing to do is unpack the Results class yourself. it has ALL info, so best starting point is this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit5/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/junit5/Karate.java

All the best :)